# Datatables pagination does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

Hello i have following code

jQuery datatables plugin (VIEW)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table1').DataTable({

            /* PROCESS NOTIFICATION */
            "processing": true,

            /* SERVER SIDE PROCESSING */
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": 
            {
                "url": "GetNonstandardProgram",
                "type": "POST"
            },


            "columnDefs":
            [
                /* HIDE ID COLUMN */
                {
                    "targets": [ 0 ],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                },

                /* ACTION COLUMN */
               {
                    "aTargets": [-1],
                    "mData": null,
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return '<a href="#" onclick="alert(\'' + full[0] + '\');">test</a>';
                    }
                }
            ],

            "bSort":false,
            "bPaginate":true,
            "iDisplayStart": 5,
            "iDisplayLength": 2

        });
    });
```

class for parameters which i downloaded (MODEL)

```
/// <summary>
    /// Class that encapsulates most common parameters sent by DataTables plugin
    /// </summary>
    public class jQueryDataTableParamModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Request sequence number sent by DataTable,
        /// same value must be returned in response
        /// </summary>       
        public string sEcho { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Text used for filtering
        /// </summary>
        public string sSearch { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of records that should be shown in table
        /// </summary>
        public int iDisplayLength { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// First record that should be shown(used for paging)
        /// </summary>
        public int iDisplayStart { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of columns in table
        /// </summary>
        public int iColumns { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of columns that are used in sorting
        /// </summary>
        public int iSortingCols { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Comma separated list of column names
        /// </summary>
        public string sColumns { get; set; }
    }
```

method which is fired by jQuery (CONTROLLER)

```
public JsonResult GetNonstandardProgram(SWIN.Models.jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
        {
```

but in this step is a problem.

[image]

all values are zeroes or null.
So the question is, why i dont see any parameter values ?!

The datatables is sending this parameters via POST

```
...
&start=5
&length=2
&search[value]=
...
&search[regex]=false
```

Thank you

Comment: can you try using `"iDisplayLength": 2` and other properties before `"serverSide": true` and let me know . cheers

Comment: hi, unfortunately it does not help but good idea. The name of the parameter is optional or it has to be named iDisplayLength ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out.
I changed name of the parameters in the class

```
public class jQueryDataTableParamModel
    {
```

to this

```
/// <summary>
/// Number of records that should be shown in table
/// </summary>
public int length { get; set; }
//public int iDisplayLength { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// First record that should be shown(used for paging)
/// </summary>
public int start { get; set; }
//public int iDisplayStart { get; set; }
```

and just used param.start and param.length